# Axios gets a new session id with every request, and also refuses to send csrf, but why?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm making a webshop with laravel api and vuejs components.

If you "add to cart" an item, it sends a post request to the api, makes a record in the "CartData" table with your session id, then saves the given product to another table (with hasMany relationship), called "CartItems", setting the cart id from the given CartData.

So at the end it should look something like this:

cartData:

| id | session_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | ASDABC123 |

cartItems:

| id | cart_data_id | product_id | product_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | *data of the product in json* |

but right now, it generates a new session data in every single request, so in every single "add to cart" click. However, when I do "session()->getId()" in the blade template, it displays the same exact session ID.

How could I fix that? Why is this happening, am I missing something?

the "buy" method in vue (app):

```
        buy(item) {
            axios.post(
                'api/cart/add',
                {
                    product_id: item.id,
                    product_data: JSON.stringify(item),
                }).then(
                    response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        toastr.success(item.name + ' added to cart!', 'Success');
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        toastr.error('Something went wrong!', 'Error');
                    });
        },
```

About the CSRF part:

```
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

this is in the bootstrap.js file that's being imported in the very first line of app.js (main js) file.

so based on the default comment in it, it should be using csrf token automatically, no?

I also have this in my header:

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

which gets the csrf token just fine.

edit 1:

When I press "addToCart", now it just returns 419 axios error.

I tried `php artisan session:table` then migrate. when I try to access `$request->session()->getId()` in the controller (to store the session data of the request, since `session()->getId()` returns a new session id evey time, it throws

```
local.ERROR: Session store not set on request. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Session store not set on request.
```

If I put `middleware(['web'])` to the route, it returns the axios 419 error, even tho I have the csrf in meta and *everything I wrote above*.

I can't believe I'm missing something so important.....

Included code snippets all in all:

addToCart method (buy) in vue component

```
buy(item) {
            axios.post(
                'api/cart/add',
                {
                    product_id: item.id,
                    product_data: JSON.stringify(item),
                }).then(
                    response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        toastr.success(item.name + ' added to cart!', 'Success');
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        toastr.error('Something went wrong!', 'Error');
                    });
        },
```

the addItem method in the cart controller is just a log that pushes "I GOT CALLED" when triggered.

api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'controller' => CartController::class], function () {
    Route::post('cart/add', 'addItem');
});
```

bootstrap.js

```
import axios from 'axios';


window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
 // this line above with the queryselector works either pushing it to window.axios and just axios. as mentioned, it shows up in the request's header.
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is in api.php which is stateless and therefore does not recognise that any request is using a previously established session.

Move your endpoint into web.php file.

Comment: oh...my...god... honestly, these small little details that stress me the hell out... thank you.

Comment: Okay so this's been bothering me. Let's say If I wanted to make an API with Laravel and store session data, and do exactly the same (cart, saved with sesison id, etc) then I would not be able to do it? Since api.php refuses to work with those csrf and session values, and generates new ones.

Comment: if your axios call is from a browser that is already using a session, then keep the routes in web.php as the axios calls can then use cookie authentication.

Comment: If you want an API called by other sites or mobile apps then use Sanctum or Passort to identify and authenticate the API session

Comment: Wow, my brain completely ignored that sanctum exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both Back-end and front-end code should be on the same server and at the same port I think you are using Vue which is a front-end application which is communicating to the back-end via API. So instead, of session try using REST API or show me your code so that I can help you more about it

Comment: I'm using Laravel, blade templates and some vue component in it. So running either `npm run dev` or `npm run build` to get that up, then just `php artisan serve` for laravel. I'm not using vue as a standalone if that's what you meant.

Comment: ok so can you share your code and how you are storing it in the session

Comment: storing what in the session? You might misunderstood something. My problem is: I want to send the current session id of the user into the database, but when I do so (with axios from a vue component), it returns 419 axios error, even tho it has the CSRF in the request header as needed. Or, if I remove the web middleware, it returns missmatching csrf, bc you can't access the $request->session() without the web middleware.

Comment: I updated the description with the main snippets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

CSRF is irrelevant, because it's just protection mechanism - not identification (but you should fix it to not getting 419). When you make requests and PHP (laravel) handles it `session_start` called, which stores `laravel_session` cookie in the browser and somewhere at the server (in files or in dB).

Can't give a clear answer, but you can debug it like this: go to the network tab in the developer tools and verify, that `Axios` actually sends session id. Token in the `Blade` view and token which sends `Axios` may be different. If `Axios` not sending token, laravel will initialize new (maybe problem here).

Comment: Just checked, the request has this in request header: `X-CSRF-TOKEN: DyWfCABHdYpoqAYJsfBuG57hde1X5fykwvd5oN0i` so it has the csrf token. yet still dies with axios 419

Comment: the method to which you send the `POST` request does it have 'web' middleware?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in the original post: "If I put middleware(['web']) to the route, it returns the axios 419 error". I can't believe I've been struggling with this for 4 hours now.